# Construction of the Lipschitz function with a given Lipschitz constant and given two values

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, approximation-theory

Let the function $f\colon [a,b] \to\mathbb{C}$ be Lipschitz and let $|f(a)| \geq c$ and $|f(b)| = c$. Is there a Lipschitz function $g$ such that $|g| \geq c,$ $g(a)=f(a),$ $ g(b)=f(b)$ and Lipschitz constant of $f-g$ is less than epsilon for any positive epsilon?

There should be some simple counterexample.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand\ep\varepsilon$Yes, it is easy to construct a counterexample here.

Indeed, if $g_\ep$ is such a function for each given real $\ep>0$ (so that $|g_\ep| \geq c$, $g_\ep(a)=f(a)$, $g_\ep(b)=f(b)$, and the Lipschitz constant of $f-g_\ep$ is less than $\ep$), then $g_\ep\to f$ pointwise (as $\ep\downarrow0$). So, it would follow that $|f|\ge c$ everywhere.

However, it is very easy to construct a Lipschitz function $f\colon [a,b] \to\mathbb{C}$ such that $|f(a)|\geq c$ and $|f(b)| = c$, but $|f(x)|<c$ for some $x\in(a,b)$.

Comment: Thank you! Sorry, but I asked the question wrong and had to update.

Comment: @Hpela : After the "update", the question looks quite incomprehensible to me.

Comment: So I updated again.

Comment: @Hpela it is considered a little rude to modify a question after the original version was correctly answered. Next time please accept Iosif's answer and post the new version separately.

Comment: @NikWeaver Sure, thank you for pointing that out

Comment: Thank you for taking it the right way!

Comment: @Hpela : Your second update is still not quite comprehensible to me. In particular, it is unclear what you mean by "it" in "Is it possible if we replace $\| \cdot \|_{\infty}$ by Lipschitz norm?". Anyhow, having two "updates", each invalidating both the previously posted question and the answer, is way too much for one MathOverflow post. So, can you please indeed follow Nik Weaver's suggestion by (i) restoring the original, comprehensible to me question and (ii) wrapping up this matter?

Comment: @IosifPinelis Done!